# What does 'num-buffers' do in gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I could only find few pages giving a one-liner explanation of `num-buffers`. Like [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-filesink.html) one.

`Number of buffers to output before sending EOS (End of Stream). Default = -1 (unlimited)`

I have a dummy pipeline using `gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc` with default `loop=False`. The pipeline loops because of `num-buffers=-1` as the default.

I don't want it to loop, which happens to be when I set `num-buffers=1` or literally any other finite number.

What does it mean to be `num-buffers=1` (or any value in that sense)?

Edit: Sample pipelines with a 10-second video

```sh
# 1. With loop=false and num-buffers=1
$> GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location=preview.h264 loop=false num-buffers=1 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! fakesink
...
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:00:00.425738029
...

# 2. With loop=false and num-buffers=10
$> GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location=preview.h264 loop=false num-buffers=10 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! fakesink
...
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:00:04.256451070
...

# 3. With neither loop flag (default=false) nor num-buffers (default=-1, unlimited)
$> GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location=preview.h264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! fakesink
...This never ends because num-buffers=-1. Why?...
```

I didn't get any warnings in any case.

Answer (score 0):

`"num-buffers"` defines how many frames will be published by a given element like `videotestsrc`. After sending `"num-buffers"`, `EOS` event is published.

I find it useful in tests when you can define number of frames and framerate and then set expectations about how many frames shall be received during given time (e.g. using `probe`).

<strike>`multifilesrc` doesn't seem to support `"num-buffers"`: it will read all files and exits (or start again when `loop=True`). You should see a warning when setting `"num-buffers"` on `multifilesrc`.</strike>

`multifilesrc` inherits from GstBaseSrc element and has `num-buffers` property. It should be used to replay a sequence of frames as video:

`gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="%08d.png" loop=true num-buffers=1000 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! ximagesink`

To replay images named `00000000.png` to `99999999.png` one after another.

For your purpose, just use `filesrc` element, not `multifilesrc`.

Comment: `EOS` is published after `num-buffers`. So if it is `-1` is it equivalent to `loop=true`? Does `num-buffers` mean how many frames to parse before sending EOS? P.S: I didn't see a warning on `multifilesrc` with `num-buffers`.

Comment: According to the documentation, it `multifilesrc` doesn't have `num-buffers`: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/multifile/multifilesrc.html?gi-language=c, but most probably this is inherited from `GstBaseSrc`. So yes, `num-buffers` == -1 should publish all frames from a given source. Updating my answer. No idea why it doesn't work then.

Comment: I've updated my question with sample pipelines. Can you check if they help?

Comment: @KaranShah I've seen it and tried it myself - I think we're using it wrong. `multifilesrc` shall be used to replay number of consecutive images using `sprintf` pattern